# Phonegap push plugin and GCM. Is it that complicated?

Tags: cordova, google-cloud-messaging, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, phonegap-pushplugin

I've been trying to get my phonegap / cordova app (for android) to work with GCM with no luck.

I've followed the documentation here: 
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push 
Setting up the sample phonegap application and sending notification using the phonegap cli built-in push function is quite easy and works as expected.

The problem starts when I'm trying to get it to work with my GCM account.
I started by setting the SENDER_ID to my GCP project number (verified it is the correct id...)

I executed "phonegap serve" from the cli and accessed the phonegap android developer app in order to receive a new device registration id and I got a new registration id (after clearing the app data).

The problem is that I think that the device doesn't really get registered with GCM because even if I enter "test123xxx" as my sender id, I still get a new device registration id so I suspect that setting the SENDER_ID alone won't do the trick and my question is how do I get my phonegap app the register the device with GCM?

Any help would be very much appreciated!
Thank you.

EDIT -
Found a solution thanks to @jcesarmobile

Apparently when using "phonegap serve" the push plugin will use phonegap internal "push" function and won't register with GCM, I had to build the app and then it worked, I used android studio to debug it on my device if this helps someone...

Comment: compile and run your app instead of "simulating" it inside the phonegap developer app

Comment: Thanks that was it! Apparently when using "phonegap serve" the push plugin will use phonegap internal "push" function and won't register with GCM, I had to build the app and then it worked, I used android studio to debug it on my device..

Comment: It will register with GCM, but not in your project, it will register with the phonegap developer app project. The thing you have to understand is, when you run the app in the developer app, you are not running your app, you are simulating or previewing it, so some things won't work the same way they should when you really run your app. Latest releases the phonegap CLI added a functionality to send push notifications to the phonegap developer app, just to check that the plugin is working.

Answer (score 1):

Please try these steps to register with GCM given in [Registering Client Apps](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/registration):

> 1. The client app obtains a registration token using the [Instance ID API](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/). The call to this API must have the authorized entity set to your app server's [sender ID](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/gcm#senderid), and the scope set to the appropriate value for GCM (depending on your platform). Refer to the API reference for full detail on this API.
> 2. The client app passes the registration token to the app server.
> 3. The app server saves the registration token and acknowledges to the client app that the process completed successfully.

If the app server fails to complete its part of the registration handshake, the client app should retry sending registration token to the server or delete the registration token.

Also, please try going through this tutorial on [Implement Push Notifications in your PhoneGap Application](http://devgirl.org/2013/07/17/tutorial-implement-push-notifications-in-your-phonegap-application/). Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, registration with GCM worked perfectly after compiling the app myself as suggested above by @jcesarmobile